# Do I need to package Alamofire's request into something like AFNetwork?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am just begin to use Swift for a project. I am choosed Alamofire for the network interface.

Because I used to use AFNetworking style interface:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                   parameters:(id)parameters
                     progress:(void (^)(NSProgress * _Nonnull))downloadProgress
                      success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull, id _Nullable))success
                      failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable, NSError * _Nonnull))failure
```

in which I can distinguish success and failure very clearly. Each one got it's own block to do its work.

But in Alamofire, the request style seems need to be mix the success and failure together in to one block:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
    .responseJSON { response in

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }

}
```

So do I have to package the Alamofire's request interface into something like AFNetworking style? or anyone has some good practice on this?

Answer (score 0):

In the response you get a lot of information including your data if successful but also an error if any (Error? optional type).

You can simply check if error is nil then it was successful.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
    .responseJSON { response in
      if response.error == nil {
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
      } else {
        //do something
      }
}
```